What caused the outage on October 3, and why was Stack Overflow unaffected?
At approximately 1500 UTC, all Stack Exchange Network sites and the Stack Exchange API were under outage.
Curiously, Stack Overflow was not affected by this outage, but Meta Stack Overflow was.
They didn’t mention the reasons on stack status as to why SE Network sites were down, so I think this issue happened suddenly, and lasted about 30 minutes.
Why was Stack Overflow unaffected by this outage? Is there any more information about this outage?
(I am just curious; there were 2 issues shown on the status page in the beginning of the October, which is unusual.)

It remained online but was definitely affected; at least some tooling was failing to load.  I'm not sure if any writes were possible at all; I didn't try.

@RyanM questions were being posted, so writes must have been possible. I also managed to edit and vote.

Not all infrastructure is shared between Stack Overflow and the SE Network. For example, the StackOverflow database is segregated from the databases for the rest of the SE Network. It's actually not unusual for SO & the rest of the network to have problems independently of each other.

SO also has lots of configuration settings different from most other sites.

Stack Overflow was also working flaky and Stack Overflow Meta was offline during that time.

What made the user ineligible to participate networkwide?

On Thursday, October 3rd, at around 14:30 UTC, the majority of the SE network - with the exception of Stack Overflow - had an unplanned service disruption. This disruption was not due to any active maintenance, which is why there was no announcement. It was also completely unrelated to an incident a couple of days before, when a code deployment broke post editing.
Short version: Our websites depend on a few different Windows clusters. We inadvertently botched one cluster, and this affected sites in the SE Network, but not Stack Overflow itself.
Some background
As former Stack DBRE Andy Mallon suggested in a comment, the database servers supporting Stack Overflow are on different physical servers than the rest of the network. And as demonstrated today, Stack Overflow can mostly continue to operate, even if the rest of the network is unavailable.
We use Windows Server Failover Clusters (WSFCs) for high availability and disaster recovery. The current configuration is a cluster for Stack Overflow only (“SO cluster”), with two nodes in New Jersey and one node in Colorado. There is a similar configuration for the rest of the Stack Exchange Network (“SE cluster”), including Meta Stack Overflow, Chat, Area 51, the rest of the network, and several other supporting databases. For historical reasons, both clusters are configured to use node majority: as long as the majority of the nodes in the cluster are online, the cluster can stay up.
Earlier this year, we added multiple servers to the SE cluster to facilitate the OpenID migration. (Yes, OpenID is currently still supported in places, including Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) (screenshot).) The database for OpenID was located in an availability group (AG) on the SE cluster, and we used these servers to migrate it elsewhere. This migration was a success.
And now, this week
Fast forward a few months, and my team was asked if the OpenID servers were still required, or if they could be shut down (immediately) and then destroyed (24 hours later). We all agreed they were no longer needed, so they were turned off on Wednesday, October 2nd. Roughly 24 hours later, the servers were destroyed, their entries were removed from AD, and that’s when the party started. When asked, we hadn’t connected the dots that those servers had originally been put into the SE cluster, and that we hadn’t gone back for any cleanup. And since they represented four out of the seven nodes, due to node majority, this caused the SE cluster to shut itself down. The SO cluster kept humming along - which is why Stack Overflow continued to work (with the exception of functionality that crosses servers), but Meta Stack Overflow was inaccessible, along with every other site on the network.
We got the cluster back online by running the following:
Stop-Cluster       -Name {SECluster name};
Start-Cluster      -Name {SECluster name} -ForceQuorum;
Start-ClusterNode  -Name {repeat for each SE cluster node}  -ForceQuorum;
Remove-ClusterNode -Name {repeat for each OpenID taxi node} -Force;

Several of us on the incident call monitored and spot-checked various places before marking the incident as mitigated. An hour later, and we marked it as resolved.
The future
Even before this incident, we had already decided that we would no longer be performing migrations by extending clusters, especially into new data centers. Barring any change in strategy, we are unlikely to bite ourselves in the same way twice.

Why did the cluster fail only after the servers were destroyed, not when they were shut down?

I might be missing something entirely here, but I don't see how a stopped or shut down node can still respond, this should have immediately broken the cluster because the quorum is impossible to meet without those stopped nodes.

@MadScientist Yes, I think you're missing that most modern clusters use dynamic quorum on the WSFC. When the nodes were gracefully shut down, the WSFC would have also gracefully removed that node's vote, allowing the cluster to maintain quorum with 3/7 nodes. But when those nodes are forcefully destroyed -- it's no longer just a matter of it being shut down. Computer objects in the AD domain start to change, and sh*t gets real.

Given that consensus seems to be that the community either doens't care or doesn't want to ban AI-generated imagery, I'm unlocking the post, rolling back to a version that includes the image. See the discussion here for  the consensus. I'll ask everyone not to start editing/rolling back again.

"For historical reasons, both clusters are configured to use node majority: as long as the majority of the nodes in the cluster are online, the cluster can stay up." Since that was one of the reasons for the outage, what is the rationale behind this historic reason? Why not simply staying online as long as a single node is online?

at work, we routinely keep shuit-down hosts around for 30 days minimum, and 6 or 12 months if they're involved in any long-run tasks.   Just-In-Case is cheap.
